# What is “open-source software licensed under the MIT license”

Tags: licensing

I wanted to use [laraspace](https://github.com/laraspace/laraspace) as my laravel boilerplate. It says in the license area "Laraspace is now an open-sourced software licensed under the MIT license." Does this mean I can use this however I wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the customary meaning of **use**, yes.

With respect to software licenses and open-source software licenses in particular, three common actions are **use**, **modify** and **distribute**. Copyright law severely limits the last action, and a license may restrict the former. However, open-source licenses in general and the MIT license in particular do not restrict your use and modify rights; they merely put some conditions on the terms of re-distribution.

Answer (score 3):

### No

It means you can use it in accordance with the terms of the [MIT license](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License).